# What does this VB6 error mean?

Tags: vb6

Run Time Error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

I am using VB6

OK here is my code

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    lblIDNumber.Caption = UserID

    With datPersonal.Recordset
        .Index = "idxid"
        .Seek "=", UserID

        LockTextboxes

    End With

End Sub

Public Sub LockTextboxes()
    With txtDateHired
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtBirthday
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtGender
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtAddress
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtContact
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtStatus
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtPosition
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtBasicSalary
        .Locked = True
    End With

    With txtReligion
        .Locked = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This error means that some object variable or with block variable is uninitialized. Sometimes errors reflect reality, you know :)

Comment: @Arvo - they do, but sometimes people need a push in the right direction. VB6 doesn't have the most helpful error messages.

Comment: There I have posted my code... The error occurs on `.Index = "idxid"`...

Comment: You should `set datPersonal.Recordset = new Recordset` before access the member fields.

Comment: @'Lenik, I'm sorry but I am using DataControl not Adodb...

Comment: Is it possible to use a `New` keyword in DataControl?

Comment: You need to bind the data control to a database. You can do this at design time by editing the properties, or you can do it in code. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/database-access-vb6-data-control-tutorial) for binding the control at design-time. Have you done anything like this?

Comment: @MarkJ... at design time, I'v already modified the properties of my DataControl. I edited its DatabaseName, RecordSource, and RecordSetType... Yes, I had a running program done with this way.

Answer (score 2):

It usually occurs when you call a method of an object which is not set.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized datPersonal.Recordset.

Comment: I have... Take a look at my code, and kindly give me some possible reason why it occurs.

Comment: @Aerohn In the code you have provided the recordset is NOT initialized, trust us.... Both datPersonal as datPersonal.Recordset are classes that need to be initialized with a `Set datPersonal=...` or `Set datPersonal.Recordset=....` line.

Comment: @Dabblernl In that code, I know that the recordset is not initialized but the DataControl was edited at design-time[properties].

Answer (score 1):

It means you are trying to use a variable, but haven't set the variable to any value. Specfically, the variable references an object rather than a value type.

Usual cause is doing something like `Dim obj As SomeClass` rather than `Dim obj As New SomeClass`, i.e. failing to set the variable to a reference to an object before using it.

Comment: How come? I had set the `idxid` as my index n my table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise classes before they can be used. Assuming datPersonal.Recordset is actually a Recordset class then you will need to do something like the following:

```
Set datPersonal.Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
```

You also need to make sure that you have added a reference to the ActiveX Data Objects in you project.

Have a look at the following:

[Add reference to ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Using a recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905900%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From your previous questions I am assuming that the datPersonal refers to a ADO Datacontrol.
The connectionstring and selection criteria of the datacontrol can be set at design-time and when the application is started, a connection and recordset is automatically opened.

The fact that you are getting this error indicates either that the connectionstring and selection was not specified or that the following code was executed :

```
Set datPersonal.Recordset = Nothing
```

Comment: I'v already modified the properties of my DataControl at designtime. I hav edited its DatabaseName, RecordSource, and RecordSetType... Yes, I had a running program done with this way.

Comment: I see. You need to determine whether the connection is successfully opened at startup. Can you check if the DataControl.Recordset is nothing as soon as form is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

maybe the problem was solved already in another way, but you could try to move the code from form_load to form_activate